# Haskell recursive find Function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have this code with the inventory list of a supermarket:

```
type Barcode = Int
type Name = String
type Price = Int
data Inventory = Inventory Barcode Name Price deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

marktInventar :: [(Int,String,Int)]
marktInventar = [ (321, "Salz",     35)
                , (432, "Butter",   95)
                , (531, "Milch",    85)
                , (235, "Eier",    145)
                , (246, "Schmalz", 245)
                , (642, "Mehl",    110)
                , (528, "Safran",  249)
                , (395, "Wurst",   345)
                , (294, "Kaese",   215)
                , (178, "Tomate",   45)
                , (378, "Banane",   75)
                , (938, "Orange",   65)
                , (491, "Kiwi",     95)
                ]
```

I was just given the list, the rest is made by myself and I hope it is correct.
Now I should build a function findArticle where I input a barcode and get the name and the price of the product. It should be a recursive function, searching through the list for the matching barcode. But how do I do this?

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you need to write `findArticle` yourself, as a homework assignment, or is this a real problem you need to solve? If the latter, you should be able to use [`Data.List.lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) if you can preprocess your inventory so that it has type `[(Int, (String, Int)]` instead; or just use `Data.List.find` directly.

Comment: What should happen if there's more than one product with a given barcode, or if there is no product with the given barcode (e.g. if the market has been robbed and there are no products left)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a recursive function yourself -- `Data.List` already exports the function `find` with this signature:

```
find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a
```

Given a barcode `bc` to look up, the predicate in your case  can be

```
\(bc', _, _) -> bc' == bc
```

The result will be `Just (_, name, price)` if the barcode is found, and `Nothing` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive version, but keep in mind it is not the best option:

```
findIt :: Barcode -> [Inventory] -> (Name, Price)
findIt code [] = ()
findIt code ((Inventory bc n p):xs) | code == bc = (n, p)
                                    | otherwise  = findIt code xs
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think this is what i looked for, but if im trying to use it i get a parse error on findit.

Comment: @MOHAWK Check your indentation.

Comment: Could not tested it since im at work (no haskell repl here :/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to name your record-style parameters, name the type so it matches a single inventory item and use the type `Inventory` to reflect the entire inventory (e.g. a list of items):

```
type Barcode = Int
type Name = String
type Price = Int
data InventoryItem = InventoryItem { barcode :: Barcode
                                   , name    :: Name
                                   , price   :: Price
                                   }
                     deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
type Inventory = [(Barcode, InventoryItem)]
```

You can then convert your `marktInventar` to an `Inventory`:

```
inventory :: Inventory
inventory = map (\(bc, n, p) -> (bc, InventoryItem bc n p)) marktInventar
```

and, as [Cactus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477476/cactus) suggests, use [`Data.List.lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) for your function `findArticle`:

```
findArticle :: Barcode -> Inventory -> Maybe InventoryItem
findArticle = lookup
```

Comment: thx for you answer, but as i do that i get the error: 
No instance for (Show (Inventory -> Maybe InventoryItem))
arising from a use of ‘print’
n a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
 sorry im a total noob and just dont get it with these types.